# How to draw multi row multi colum table with many filelds

Tags: tables

[image]

I need to create a table of the type given below. But I am not getting this. Could anyone here help me? Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  By the way, this table has too much (vertical) lines

Answer (score 1):

You can have something neater than your image using the `makecell` package (allows for linebreaks inside cells, and common formatting of column heads), `booktabs` and `siunitx` for the formatting of columns with numerical values

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=-3.2, table-number-alignment=center}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=2.2]}
\newcolumntype{U}{S[table-format=1.2]}

\begin{document}

{\centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}lc STTSSTU@{\,}}
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\thead{Paired Samples Test}} \\
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\thead{Paired Differences}} & & \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\multirowthead{4}{Type\\of test} & \multirowthead{4}{Comparison} & {\multirowthead{4}{Mean}} & {\multirowthead{4}{Std.\\Deviation}} & {\multirowthead{4}{Std.\\Error Mean}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{95\% Confidence\\Interval of the\\ Difference}}
& {\multirowthead{4}{\boldmath$t$ value}} & {\multirowthead{4}{d.f.}}\\%
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
& & & & & {\thead{Lower}} & {\thead{Upper}} & & \\
\midrule
Pair 1 & \makecell{Hybrid GA\\Path Cost} & -507.00 & 54.01 & 31.18 & -641.17 & -372.83 & -16.26 &2.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`multirow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package.  Note, that the first argument to the `\multirow` represents the height of the *generated* cell in displayed lines-it does not have to correspond to the amount of *logical* lines (those that you end with `\\` in the source).

Second argument is the width of the generated column or `*` to calculate it automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{5em}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Paired Samples Test} \\
  \hline
  \multirow{5}{3em}{Type of test} & 
    \multirow{5}{*}{Comparison} & 
      \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Paired Differences} &
        \multirow{5}{*}{$t$ value} &
          \multirow{5}{*}{d.f.} \\
  \cline{3-7}
  & & \multirow{4}{*}{Mean} &
        \multirow{4}{4em}{Std.\ Deviation} &
          \multirow{4}{3em}{Std.\ Error Mean} &
            \multicolumn{2}{|p{7em}|}{\centering 95\% Confidence Interval     of the Difference} &
            & \\
  \cline{6-7}
  & & & & & Lower & Upper & & \\
  \hline
  Pair 1 & Hybrid GA Path Cost & -507.00 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]